# Diffeomorphism $\Leftrightarrow$ injective

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

My question is really simple, I would like to prove a local diffeomorphism $f:U\to \mathbb R^m$ is a global diffeomorphism over its image $V=f(U)$ if and only if it's an injective function.

The $\Rightarrow$ part is easy, I've already proved a local diffeomorphism is an open function, but I don't know how to use this fact to prove the converse.

Comment: It's bijective so it has an inverse. The inverse is smooth locally near any $p$ by the inverse function theorem, and thus globally.

Comment: @juanarroyo could you give me what your version of the inverse function theorem is? the version I know is http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~nwallach/inverse[1].pdf

Comment: That's the one. Using that you can define a smooth inverse in a neighborhood of each point in $f(U)$. A map that is smooth in a nbhd of each point is smooth.

Comment: Related? [Is open (topological) smooth embedding equivalent to injective local (homeomorphism) diffeomorphism?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4110871/is-open-topological-smooth-embedding-equivalent-to-injective-local-homeomorph)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $x\in V$, let $W\subseteq U$ be an open neighborhood of $f^{-1}(x)$ on which $f$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image.  That is, $f$ restricts to a diffeomorphism $f|_W:W\to f(W)$.  Then the restriction of $f^{-1}$ to $f(W)$ is smooth, since it is the inverse of the diffeomorphism $f|_W$.  But $f(W)$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ and smoothness is a local property, so $f^{-1}$ is smooth at $x$.  Since $x\in V$ was arbitrary, this proves $f^{-1}$ is smooth.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Did you use the fact $f$ is an open function?

Comment: I used the fact that $f(W)$ is open...this follows from the fact that $f$ is open, but also is probably just directly part of your definition of "local diffeomorphism".  And you need to know that $V$ is open for it to even make sense to talk about $f:U\to V$ being a diffeomorphism.

Comment: @EricWofsey, how you use the hypothesis the $f$ is injective? I imagine that you use the hypothesis to ensure that $|f^{-1}(x)| = 1$ and obtain the existence of this $W$, but I think $W$ exists because $f$ is a local diffeomorphism. I can't see how the injectiveness of $f$ was used.

Comment: $f^{-1}$ does not even exist as a function unless $f$ is injective.

Comment: Related? [Is open (topological) smooth embedding equivalent to injective local (homeomorphism) diffeomorphism?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4110871/is-open-topological-smooth-embedding-equivalent-to-injective-local-homeomorph)